# how to pipenv install 64 bit packages in virtual environement (.virtualenvs) while having both 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I have installed both 64 and 32 bit versions of python in Windows 10:

- 64 bit python (along with Visual Studio)
- 32 bit python (independently, path is registered in environments path)

I am using VS Code to work on python projects. I am able to use any version of 
installed python including virtualenvs. Also intellisense and debugging is going great.

But when i am trying to use TensorFlow i.e. only available for 64 bit python. I am not finding any way to say hey use 64 bit python for this Virtual environment (pipenv).

Note: I want to use 32 bit as default in VS Code for my other projects, so changing the env path variable to 32/64 bit python again is not preferable idea.

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! Like python, it is quite easy but remain unexplored for bit of time for me:)

Just used my 64 bit python to create the pipenv.

```
 & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36
_64\python.exe' -m pipenv shell
```

**Note:**

- & is used to tell powershell to consider exe path as command but not
  string.
- If your 64 bit python has not pipenv installed consider
  adding it first with below command

> ```
> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36
> _64\python.exe' -m pip install pipenv
> ```